# how to schedule the execution of an async function in python and immediately return

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I need to implement a proxy server in python that forwards client requests to some api if it doesn't have the data in it's cache. The requirement for when the data isn't present in the cache, is to not let the client wait at all but rather send back something like "you'll have your data soon" and in the meanwhile send a request to the api. It was my understanding I need to use async/await for this, but I could not make this work no matter what I tried. I am using asyncio and aiohttp libraries for this.
So let's say I have my function that sends a request to the api:

```
async def fetch(url, page_num):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            resp = await response.json()
            cache[page_num] = (resp, datetime.now())
            return resp
```

what I would like is the following behavior:

```
if not_in_cache(page_number):
    fetch(url, page_number) #this needs to return immediately so the client won't wait!!!
    return Response("we're working on it") #send back a response without data
```

So on the one hand I want the method to immediately return a response to the client, but in the background I want it to get the data and store it in the cache. How can you accomplish that with async/await?

Answer (score 1):

Create a task. Instead of:

```
if not_in_cache(page_number):
    await fetch(url, page_number)
    return Response(...)
```

write:

```
if not_in_cache(page_number):
    asyncio.create_task(fetch(url, page_number))
    return Response(...)
```

Don't forget to read the asyncio docs: [Coroutines and Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)